# Load different iframes from dropdown list

Tags: jquery, iframe, drop-down-menu

I want to load a different iframe depending on the choice from the dropdown list. I don't want to use any 'GO' button, just after selecting the choice from dropdown it opens a specific iframe which corresponds with the specific selection. I have done this thing without iframes, but by 'hiding' the unnecessary content, however the page became huge and was loading up very slow.
this is the html:

```
<select id="selector">
    <option value="opt0"  id="opt0">select movie</option>
    <option value="opt1"  id="opt1">movie 2</option>
    <option value="opt2"  id="opt2">movie 3</option>
    <option value="opt3"  id="opt3">movie 4</option>
</select>
```

I would really like to use jquery for this, as I'm not really familiar with php.
Underneath the selection there will be a specific iframe, different for each of the selections from dropdown.
thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged this question with jQuery, I assume that it would be better to use jQuery to make your code simpler. You already have an `id` with the `<select>` tag. Remove the `id` from the `<option>` tags and use URLs for the `value` attribute.

```
<select id="selector">
    <option value="0">select movie</option>
    <option value="./movie2">movie 2</option>
    <option value="./movie3">movie 3</option>
    <option value="./movie4">movie 4</option>
</select>
```

And bind an `onchange` event to the `<select>` tag this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selector").change(function(){
        $("#iframeId").attr("src", $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Now when you change the value of the `<select>` tag, the content in the `iframe` changes as per the URL given in the `<option>`'s value.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/292wF/

Comment: This is as great as it's simple. thank you a lot @PraveenKumar